# 15 second delay on second request in node

Tags: node.js, ssl, https, request, delay

I have a server to which a need to send multiple http requests. But every request except the first triggers a ~15 second delay.

If I send the requests from linux console, POSTman or Fiddler it works great, without delay, but I cannot get it to work from node.

I have tried with `https.get()`, `request`, sockets and even forking a request in a separate file. But the delay is still there. The server replies with the proper `Connection: close` header. The server is an nginx server.

The only time it works from node is if I put my request in a separate script and runs only this script. It probably works because node exits and releases the connection after the request.

I have tried with `agent: false` and I'm sending `Connection: close` to the server but why does it take 15 seconds for it to close, and why doesn't this happen when using Fiddler or POSTman?

Edit: Added code. This code works perfectly the first time I run it, but if I run it twice or more the delay appears. It's the second function that causes the delay, the first function works fine.

```
async.waterfall([
  function(cb) {
    console.log('making first connection');
    var post_data = querystring.stringify({
                    'login' : username,
                    'password'  : password
                });
    var options = {
                    hostname: 'hostname',
                    port: 443,
                    path: '/path',
                    method: 'POST',
                    agent: agent,
                    pool: false,
                    keepAlive: false,
                    followRedirect: false,      
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                        'Content-Length': post_data.length
                    }  
                };          
                // get headers including cookie
                var req = https.request(options, function(res) {
                    console.log("statusCode: ", res.statusCode);
                    cb(null, res.headers)
                });

                req.write(post_data);
                req.end(); 
            },
  function(header, cb) {
    console.log('making second connection');    
    https.request({
                    host: 'my.server',
                    path: '/' + encodeURIComponent(params),
                    port: 443,
                    method: 'GET',
                    headers: {
                        'Cookie': 'IFLANG=eng;SESSID=somesession',
                        'Connection': 'Close',
                        'Content-Length': 0
                    }
                }, function(res) {
                    console.log(res.headers);
                }).on('error', function(err){
                    console.log(err);
                }).end();
         },    
        ], function (err, result) {
            if(err)
                console.error(err);
            callback(err, result);
        });
```

Update: This code causes the same delay, but when running it as a curl command from the command line I can hammer the server without any delay.

```
var args = [
  'https://myserver' + encodeURIComponent( urlPath ),
  '-k',
  '-v',
  '-0',
  '--no-keepalive',
  '-b SESSID=someSessionIDfromFirstFunction',
];

child_process.spawn('curl', args);
```

Comment: Can you show the script which is exhibiting problems?

Comment: Please show us the actual code that is giving you problems.  Questions here should nearly always contain relevant portions of your ACTUAL code.  That's the only way we can help you specifically and accurately.